# Problemas al mostrar contenido en jsp, anteriormente ocultado

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web. En este caso, tengo un botón en el `jsp` que al pulsarlo debe mostrar una tabla con los datos (traídos desde el `servlet`, que a su vez hace una consulta a la base de datos para recogerlos). El caso es que la tabla la he puesto con `display:none`. Y en el botón he puesto una llamada a una función `javaScript` que muestra el contenido de esa tabla. El caso es que cuando pulsas el botón, te muestra la tabla menos de un segundo y vuelve a desaparecer. No se por qué puede ser...a ver si tenéis idea de por qué puede ser.La idea, en resumen, es que no haya nada, y que cuando se pulse el botón, aparezca la tabla, y ya se quede ahí. Gracias de antemano.

**FUNCION JavaScript**

`<script>
  function mostrar(){
      document.getElementById('tabla').style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>`

**Botón**

`<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="mostrar()" href="ExpertoController?action=lista" role="button">Ver la lista de software evaluables</a></p>`

**Tabla**

```html
<div  id="tabla" style = "display:none;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>${columna1}</th>
        <th>${columna2}</th>
        <th>${columna3}</th>
     </tr>
     <c:forEach items="${listaSoftware}" var="software" varStatus="status" >
      <tr> 
          <td>${software.id}</td>
   <td>${software.nombre}</td>
   <td>${software.notaMedia}</td>
      </tr>
     </c:forEach> 
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el botón, tienes un elemento `a` con un href, que te lleva a una pagina, que según lo que dices, es la misma pagina en la que estás, lo cual la estas refrescando.

Si necesitas un href que no conduzca a ninguna parte añádele `javascript: void(0)`:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="mostrar()" href="javascript: void(0)" role="button">Ver la lista de software evaluables</a></p>
```

Comment: Antes de nada, gracias por la respuesta Francisco. El caso es que en el href tengo que poner el servlet que pilla los objetos de la base de datos. Entonces no puedo usar tu alternativa, porque es necesario el href con la redireccion al servlet.

Comment: En ese caso tendras que mostrar la tabla de otra manera, si refrescas la pagina, se va a perder los cambios siempre si o si. La alternativa seria o usar un boton diferente para mostrar o AJAX